# Undo Inserting or Updating Google Sheet Automation Using OCR and Tesseract

Tags: python, pandas, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I writed a code to scan serial numbers images and create a dataframe which i'll call it "df_sn".
And i have a google sheet where i want to change  (update or insert a cell) with a chosen serial number of the df_sn dataframe.

Question for action bifurcation due to my need for Inserting new row or Updating existing rows.

Created lists for possibilities in writing

```
updating = ['Updating', 'updating', 'update', '2']
inserting= ['inserting', 'Inserting', 'insert', '1']
```

Input the desirable action

```
desirable_action = input("Do You Want Start An Inserting Or Updating Process? ")
```

Below i created some if conditions for the Updating

```
if desirable_action in updating:
  print('Updating ' + "Process Started!")
  desirable_row = input("Which row do you want to update? ")
  desirable_col = input("Which column do you want to update? ")
  cell = sheet.cell(desirable_row,desirable_col)
  print("Cell Before Update: ", cell)
```

The below line updates the cell (row, col) with a value from the df_sn by index and column pattern

```
sheet.update_cell(desirable_row,desirable_col,df_sn.at[1,'Serial Number'])

print('Cell After Update: ', cell)
```

So what i need and can't think of way to solve it is:

1. To be able to undo the updating just like the input function id est by a dialog box

Comment: AFAIK, There is no undo request.  You need to store the previous value somewhere and re-send update cell request with the previous value - effectively, a undo.

Comment: I thought of that but the way i imagined was appending the old values to a list and call the values by index when needed just like you said, however that would impose a loop to make the "undo" process more duable. And this loop would have to take the last index and create an object which will be inserted in the "value" part of the updated_cell method. But can't think of way to do it

Comment: Maybe [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) or deque might help.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the @TheMaster that gave it the "queue" idea.

So inside my if condition i inserted an append method to a queue

```
undo_storage = []

updating = ['Updating', 'updating', 'update', '2']
undo = ["Undo", "undo"]
inserting =['inserting', 'Inserting', 'insert', '1']

desirable_action = []

while desirable_action != 'q':
  desirable_action = input("Do You Want to Start An Inserting Process, Updating Process Or Undo the Previous Change? (press q to quit) ")

if desirable_action in updating:
  print('Updating ' + "Process Started!")

  desirable_row = input("Which row do you want to update? ")

  desirable_col = input("Which column do you want to update? ")

  old_value = sheet.cell(desirable_row,desirable_col)

  undo_storage.append(old_value.value)

  print("Cell Before Update: ", old_value)

  sheet.update_cell(desirable_row,desirable_col,df_sn.at[1,'Serial Number'])

  new_value = sheet.cell(desirable_row,desirable_col)

  print('Cell After Update: ', new_value)
```

And you can see there is one new line:

```
  undo_storage.append(old_value.value)
```

So inside if condition which is inside a while loop i did the code save the old_value in a queue list. And like a regular "store line" the first element in is the first element out (FIFO).

After updating a cell in the sheet and want to undo the change i can answer "undo" to the first question and the below if condition will be ran:

```
if desirable_action in undo:
sheet.update_cell(desirable_row,desirable_col,undo_storage.pop(0))
print("Undo aplied! Cell after undo: ",old_value)
```

The "`undo_storage.pop(0)`" will make the value stored in the queue list be the new value to be inserted in the cell. Done! Undo functionality working well!

Comment: ["deque"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) instead of plain lists would improve performance.